# Libgdx android compatibility issues

Tags: android, libgdx

I deployed a game as internal test release to android developer console. After 2 days review google published my game with some compatibility issues.

It says "the following APIs are greylisted and Google cannot guarantee that they will work on existing versions of android. Dome may be already restricted for your target SDK."

And they give the incompatible API list as StrictMode policy violation:

```
java.nio.Buffer-address
android.content.context-bindServiceAsUser
android.media.AudioTrack-getLatency
```

.....

There are 11 more. But I dont know how to solve this issue. I really appreciate any answer. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using any libraries besides LibGDX? Just searched the LibGDX source and it doesn't call any of those three APIs.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your attention. Reported stack trace is as follows:

Comment: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/Buffer;->_elementSizeShift:I
 at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
 at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.init(Native Method)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:117)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:112)

Comment: another one. StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Ljava/nio/Buffer;->limit:I
 at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
 at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.init(Native Method)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:117)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:112)

Comment: What version of LibGDX is it? These particular calls have been removed in the newly released LibGDX 1.9.10.

Comment: Oh!. 1.9.8. I'll try 1.9.10. Thank you.